# $\mu(E)\ge \nu(E)\ \forall E\in A\ \Rightarrow\ \mu(\cup E)\ge\nu(\cup E)$? Here $\mu,\nu$ are probability measures on a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

$\mu(E)\ge \nu(E)\ \forall E\in A\ \Rightarrow\ \mu(\cup E)\ge\nu(\cup E)$?

A. Here $\mu,\nu$ are probability measures on a $\sigma$-algebra $M$ on a set $X$. We can assume that arbitrary unions of the elements of $A$ are measurable. Of course, $A\subset M$. (This was already answered negatively below.)

B. In addition, assume $E,E'\in A\ \Rightarrow\ E\subset E'$ or $E'\subset E$. [B. added Feb 6th; originally missing.]

Comment: What is $A$? And are you sure you want to allow arbitrary unions, or just countable unions?

Comment: There are simple counterexamples where $A$ contains just two sets..

Comment: You are right. I was too much thinking "B." (which I now added above), so I looked at wrong direction and did not even observe that at least "A." is false. Thank you all three for the answer of "A.".

Answer (score 1):

On $\{1,2,3,4\}$ let $\mu$ be uniform on $\{2,4\}$ and $\nu$ be uniform on $\{1,3\}$. Let $A$ consist of just the two sets $E_1:=\{1,2\}$ and $E_2:=\{2,3\}$ (note $A$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra). Then $\mu(E_1)=\nu(E_1)=\frac12$ and $\mu(E_2)=\nu(E_2)= \frac12$ but $\mu(E_1\cup E_2)=\frac12 <1=\nu(E_1\cup E_2)$.